# subsetting with Relational Operator !=

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe df with various columns.

In column `df$xyz` I have about 20 character variables.
I want to retain 3 variables `("HL%", "HH$", "LL$")` and all other variables `("truncated", "kk$", "hhb"...)` should be replaced with `"other"`.

Thats my data frame:

```
xz   xyz 
2.5  HL%
4.4  HH$
9.3  kk$
2.4  kk$
4.5  LL$
5.6  truncated
```

I need:

```
xz   xyz 
2.5  HL%
4.4  HH$
9.3  other
2.4  other
4.5  LL$
5.6  other
```

I tried:

```
df$xyz[df$xyz!="HL%"|
         df$xyz!="HH$"|
         df$xyz!="LL$"] <- "other"
```

That doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Your `xyz` column is probably a factor. Try showing us an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that replicates the problem.

Comment: also check out `%in%` to save you some typing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @nya already stated in comments your `df$xyz` is probably a factor variable, check with `str(df)`.

```
str(df)
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  2 variables:
#  $ xz : num  2.5 4.4 9.3 2.4 4.5 5.6
#  $ xyz: Factor w/ 6 levels "HH$","HL%","kk$",..: 2 1 6 6 4 6
```

In this case first update your factor levels with the new level `"other"` you introduce. Otherwise skip this step.

```
levels(df$xyz) <- c(levels(df$xyz), "other")
```

After that just do.

```
df$xyz[-which(df$xyz %in% c("HL%", "HH$", "LL$"))] <- "other"
```

Your approach will also work, but you need to replace the `|` with `&`.